# Is there any way to change my Facebook username more than once?

Tags: facebook, username

I was wondering if there was some way I could go into the site's code and directly edit the variable for my username? Or anything like that?

Comment: Another hack: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200675236469983&answer_id=10202786475569641

Comment: It's simple.Make a facebook page from your personal facebook account and then transfer your account's name to the newly made page.After that, delete the page and then change your username.

Answer (score 2):

In short no. However there seems to be a hack out there (I've not tested this)

> As per Facebook’s condition and terms, it does not allow the users to
>   change their facebook usernameafter setting one. But this simple
>   technic allows to do that. To change your username, you just have to
>   deactivate your account. But don’t worry you will not loss any data,
>   because you can re-activate on next log in. Follow the steps below.
>
> Step 1 Go to account settings from the button on top right Click on
>   ‘Security’ Then click the option ‘Deactivate your account.’ Give
>   explanation as “Its temporary”.
>
> Step 2 Then log in again with your email and password. Done Your
>   account is re-activated.
>
> Step 3 Go to account settings from the button
>   on top right. Edit username. Done. Your account username is changed.

Source:
[How can change username of facebook more than once?](http://ajithabhks.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/how-can-change-username-of-facebook.html)

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work. Thanks for trying though, and I think you may be confusing username with my actual facebook name. I am speaking of the username that dictates the url of the profile page.

Comment: yea, I was a bit sceptical. My understanding, from a developers point of view, is the reason you can't change the username anymore is that since the update the username is acting as a permalink to your content. to change it facebook would have to find literally every piece of data in their database about you and modify that username. If everyone had the ability to do this willy nilly it could potentially grind the site to a halt.

Comment: if it's an extremely important situation you can contact facebook and try to get them to make the modification. Though it's unlikely they'll help you unless you're a large company or dealing with a trademark infringement regarding your username and someone else's

Comment: I'm kind of skeptical of anyone who spells >=one word per sentence incorrectly

Comment: haha, yea I could've gone through and fixed their errors...but meh.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you need to deactivate your account to change User Name. See the following blogspot how to do it: [Change Facebook Login ID](http://dadecoder.blogspot.in/2013/01/change-facebook-login-id.html)

I have changed my Facebook ID without any problems.

Comment: Please add the relevant info in the answer instead of linking to your blog, otherwise your answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: The title of this question asks specifically about changing it *more than once* -- your blog only gives info on how to change it that first time.

Comment: Why didn't you read the question?